# delete contact in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem I want to do a method that deletes from the notebook gives the contact having as id the contact gives and this method returns the new character representing the notebook after the deletion, I know that I have to redo a new notebook and with a loop I go through the lines of the old notebook one by one then and then I add those for which the ID does not match in the new notebook, here is what I have already done:

```
public static String deleteThisContactInCarnet (String idContact, String notebook)
String newCarnet;
        String Endbook;
        int lines = notebook.split (System.lineSeparator ()). length;
        for (int i = 0, n = rows; i <n; i ++) {
            String contact = book.StringAt (i);
            if (getContactId (contact)! = idContact) {
                return newCarnet = contact + System.lineSeparator ();
            }
        }
        return (bookFinal = book.replace (newCarnet, ""));
```

I do not see how to pass between each line of the notebook. . .
Does anyone have a suggestion? Thank you very much and good day !

Comment: You're using `split` on the `notebook`to break it into an array of lines..  Then you get the `length` of that array, keep the length and throw away the actual lines.  Wouldn't it make more sense to keep that array of lines instead of discarding it?

Comment: I recommend against using `System.lineSeparator()` as argument to split, unless you're absolutely certain that the string with contacts never leaves the device where this is running. `System.lineSeparator()` is platform-dependent.

Comment: Just saying: using a raw string as contact notebook is a very broken design right from the start. Consider to create a class that contains a single contact, and then simply put those into a LIST for example. Most the trouble you are facing is based on that: using the wrong abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
    public static String deleteThisContactInCarnet( String idContact, String notebook ) {
        String newBook = "";
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList( notebook.split( System.lineSeparator() ) );
        lines.sort( ( String a, String b ) -> a.split( "|" )[1].compareTo( b.split( "|" )[1] ) );
        for ( int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ ) {
            String contact = lines.get( i );
            if ( !contact.contains( idContact ) ) {
                newBook += contact + System.lineSeparator();
            }
        }
        return newBook;
    }
```

Comment: Oh Thanks man ! oh thank you very much man that gives! Sorry to bother you but I have one last question how do I compare the names of each contact and sort them alphabetically with a StringTokenizer? i know with a split but i don't want to use an array. Have a nice day and Thank you !

Comment: Can you show what exactly one line of contact looks like? Otherwise I can't tell how to sort it.

Comment: oh sure a contact line looks like this: "3|last name|first name|email|phone" with 
with "|" being String INFO_CONTACT_SEPARATOR.

Comment: I've added sorting to the answer.